# Nagios-Monitoring the webservices

Tags: nagios

I am new to Nagios.We need to configure in nagios for monitoring a  web service.

We have given below command in nagios server:

```
check_http_I!XX.X.XXX.X!-k 'SOAPAction: "urn:LEOACTIVEService"' -r '<ns:_LEO_ERROR_FND>N</ns:_LEO_ERROR_FND>' -T text/xml -P '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"<soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><leo:leoactive><\!--Optional:--><leo:param0><\!--Optional:--><leo:_EXTRACTS><\!--Optional:--><leo:_LEO_ERROR_FND></leo:_LEO_ERROR_FND></leo:_EXTRACTS></leo:param0></leo:leoactive></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>' -p 10010 -u
```

http://XX.X.XXX.X:10010/web/services/LEOACTIVEService/LEOACTIVE

Please advise getting error.
Not sure if any error in configuration script.Kindly let me know if any further information required.

Thanks In Advance!!

Comment: In your question are missing few things. It is your own script?
What error you get?
Do you have `check_http_I` command defined in config like `commands.cfg`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply..Sorry for delay in response.yes we have chech_http_I in commands.cfg
define command{
        command_name    check_http_I
        command_line    $USER2$/check_http -I $ARG1$ -t 60 $ARG2$ $ARG3$ $ARG4$ $ARG5$
        }

Comment: Can you try run your script `check_http` in terminal with your parameters? Something like that: `./check_http -I XX.X.XXX.X -t 60 -k 'SOAPAction: "urn:LEOACTIVEService"' -r '<ns:_LEO_ERROR_FND>N</ns:_LEO_ERROR_FND>' -T text/xml -P '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"<soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><leo:leoactive><\!--Optional:--><leo:param0><\!--Optional:--><leo:_EXTRACTS><\!--Optional:--><leo:_LEO_ERROR_FND></leo:_LEO_ERROR_FND></leo:_EXTRACTS></leo:param0></leo:leoactive></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>' -p 10010 -u`